# MySQL and UTF-8

Tags: sql, mysql, unicode, utf-8

In MySQL, what is the difference between doing:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

And:

```
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
```

I've taken a look at [Connection Character Sets and Collations MySQL documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) but I'm still a bit confused... Do both commands need to be issued in order to make MySQL UTF-8 aware? Or [is SET NAMES enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279)?

Comment: Note that MySQL's 'utf8' is actually just a small subset of UTF-8 (up to 3 bytes). Use 'utf8mb4' instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24487309/664132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### SET NAMES

`SET NAMES` indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL statements to the server. That means that `SET NAMES 'cp1251'` tells the server “future incoming messages from this client are in character set cp1251.”  It also specifies the character set that the server should use for sending results back to the client.

### SET CHARACTER SET

`SET CHARACTER SET` is similar to `SET NAMES`, but sets `character_set_connection` and `collation_connection` to `character_set_database` and `collation_database`. A `SET CHARACTER SET x` statement is equivalent to these three statements:

```
SET character_set_client = x;
SET character_set_results = x;
SET collation_connection = @@collation_database;
```

---

> Do both commands need to be issued in order to make MySQL UTF-8 aware? Or is SET NAMES enough?

SET NAMES is enough.

Comment: Keep in mind that `SET NAMES` doesn't notify the client lib (libmysql.dll) about the change in character encoding. This might affect the result of client lib functions like mysql\_real\_escape\_string(). If your application relies on real\_escape\_string() you should look for a function/method in your API that also takes care of the client-side aspect of the encoding. For the C API that would be http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-set-character-set.html , for php-mysql http://docs.php.net/mysql_set_charset

Comment: @VolkerK: Thanks for the `mysql_set_charset()` link, is there a PDO equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

SET NAMES has encoding for connection, and SET CHARACTER SET is encoding for table. Using both command is highly recomment, to avoid terrible charter problems...