# $_GET doesn't work correctly with Internet Explorer (UTF-8)

Tags: php, internet-explorer, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to GET values from url
and I have ended up with a problem in IE
but all other browsers it works great.

This is my issue:

If text is some UTF-8 text as example:

```
$x=$_GET['txt'];
echo $x;
```

I got

> ???????

only in IE

still same problem and this is my all code

```
 <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$x=$_GET['id'];
echo $x;
?>
```

try with this word in id

سسسسسسس

Comment: Please provide more details. I.e. The code you're using for the form etc

Comment: updated my answer with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this meta tag inside the `<head>` if it's a charset issue (as an alternative to using `header` inside PHP):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

**UPDATE**

If you're not encoding the value of `x` from the URL you should do something like:

```
<a href="page.php?x=<?php echo urlencode($string)?>">Link</a>
```

Using your sample text (سسسسسسس), once that's encoded using `urlencode` it should like this:

```
%D8%B3%D8%B3%D8%B3%D8%B3%D8%B3%D8%B3%D8%B3
```

I got it working by adding a charset meta tag and doing a simple `urldecode`:

```
echo urldecode($_GET['x']);
```

See screenshot on IE:
[image]

Comment: amazing but what if i want to put this into sql search routine that contain % ? ? ?

Comment: you need to somehow decode it before feeding it to your SQL query e.g. assuming you're using simple query `$search = mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($_GET['x']));` something like that.

Comment: i will mark this as best answer because you put me on the right way and i use this with my app jquery ajax based :D

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your page so the browser will recognize its encoding correctly. Mostly sending a proper header is enough:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

This is for `UTF8` but you can send any encoding you want.

Answer (score 0):

try adding: [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) & [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) around your `$x`

Comment: didn't understood you quite well, try using these functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php && http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php ... and also encode your files with UTF-8, and add the content-type in your HTML META tags

Answer (score 0):

As you already stated yourself this could depending on the browsers character encoding settings. Try the utf8-function in PHP like
http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.utf8-decode.php
and
http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.utf8-encode.php
(:

Also look here:
[Handling unicode values in GET parameters with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167960/handling-unicode-values-in-get-parameters-with-php)