# URL encoding spanish words

Tags: php, javascript, html, urlencode, encode

I'm building a Spanish dictionary. I get the definitions from www.rae.es . Problem:

the search engine doesn't work with acute accents ( á é í ó ú ). The output is an error message from rae.es stating that the word is not recognized. For example: for the word "baúl", this comes up (translated): "The word baÃºl isn't registered in the dictionary."

How can I use urlencode() or other function to solve this problem? Please check the code by right click and inspect element with Google Chrome, Safari or Firefox.

http://verbum.xtrweb.com/verbumpost.php?word=ba%C3%BAl&word0=

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php do what you want

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167960/handling-unicode-values-in-get-parameters-with-php

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `urlencode(utf8_encode($string))` instead of just `urlencode($string)`.

Comment: Let's see. The browser sends UTF-8-encoded GET requests. PHP decodes them as latin1. How is `urlencode()` going to help?

Comment: if my variable is $words , should I write it as                       <?php   urlencode(utf8_encode($words)) ?>

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlentities on your search term and try using post, not get:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php